# How to Create New Column in Pandas From Two Existing Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes, call them *A* and *B*. In *A* is most of my data (it's 110 million rows long), while *B* contains information I'd like to add (it's a dataframe that lists all the identifiers and counties). In dataframe *A*, I have a column called *identifier*. In dataframe *B*, I have two columns, *identifier* and *county*. I want to be able to merge the dataframes such that a new dataframe is created where I preserve all of the information in *A*, while also adding a new column *county* where I use the information provided in *B* to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
import pandas as pd
data_A = {'incident_date':['ert','szd','vfd','dvb','sfa','iop'] \
        ,'incident':['A','B','A','C','B','F']
        }


data_B = {'incident':['A','B','C','D','E'] \
        , 'number':[1,1,3,23,23]}

df_a = pd.DataFrame(data_A)
df_b = pd.DataFrame(data_B)
```

Inorder to preserve you df_A which has million rows

```
df_ans = df_a.merge(df_b[['number','incident']], on='incident',how='left')
```

The output

```
print(df_ans)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA0cH.png)

**Note:- There is NaN value since that value was not present in 2nd Dataframe**